# constructing a binary search tree in java

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to construct this binary search tree in Java: 
[image]
Here's my linked binary search tree implementation class:

```
/**
 * LinkedBinarySearchTree implements the BinarySearchTreeADT interface 
 * with links.
 * 
 * @author Java Foundations
 * @version 4.0
 */
public class LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> extends LinkedBinaryTree<T>
                                        implements BinarySearchTreeADT<T>
{
    /**
     * Creates an empty binary search tree.
     */
    public LinkedBinarySearchTree() 
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a binary search with the specified element as its root.
     *
     * @param element the element that will be the root of the new binary
     *        search tree
     */
    public LinkedBinarySearchTree(T element) 
    {
        super(element);

        if (!(element instanceof Comparable))
            throw new NonComparableElementException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified object to the binary search tree in the
     * appropriate position according to its natural order.  Note that
     * equal elements are added to the right.
     *
     * @param element the element to be added to the binary search tree
     */
    public void addElement(T element) 
    {
        if (!(element instanceof Comparable))
            throw new NonComparableElementException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");

        Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>)element;

        if (isEmpty())
            root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
        else 
        {
            if (comparableElement.compareTo(root.getElement()) < 0)
            {
                if (root.getLeft() == null) 
                    this.getRootNode().setLeft(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
                else
                    addElement(element, root.getLeft());
            }
            else
            {
                if (root.getRight() == null) 
                    this.getRootNode().setRight(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
                else
                    addElement(element, root.getRight());
            }
        }
        modCount++;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified object to the binary search tree in the
     * appropriate position according to its natural order.  Note that
     * equal elements are added to the right.
     *
     * @param element the element to be added to the binary search tree
     */
    private void addElement(T element, BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
    {
        Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>)element;

        if (comparableElement.compareTo(node.getElement()) < 0)
        {
            if (node.getLeft() == null) 
                node.setLeft(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
            else
                addElement(element, node.getLeft());
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.getRight() == null) 
                node.setRight(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
            else
                addElement(element, node.getRight());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Removes the first element that matches the specified target
     * element from the binary search tree and returns a reference to
     * it.  Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the specified target
     * element is not found in the binary search tree.
     *
     * @param targetElement the element being sought in the binary search tree
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if the target element is not found
     */
    public T removeElement(T targetElement)
                                  throws ElementNotFoundException 
    {
        T result = null;

        if (isEmpty())
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");
        else
        {
            BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = null;
            if (((Comparable<T>)targetElement).equals(root.element)) 
            {
                result =  root.element;
                BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = replacement(root);
                if (temp == null)
                    root = null;
                else 
                {
                    root.element = temp.element;
                    root.setRight(temp.right);
                    root.setLeft(temp.left);
                }

                modCount--;
            }
            else 
            {                
                parent = root;
                if (((Comparable)targetElement).compareTo(root.element) < 0)
                    result = removeElement(targetElement, root.getLeft(), parent);
                else
                    result = removeElement(targetElement, root.getRight(), parent);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first element that matches the specified target
     * element from the binary search tree and returns a reference to
     * it.  Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the specified target
     * element is not found in the binary search tree.
     *
     * @param targetElement the element being sought in the binary search tree
     * @param node the node from which to search
     * @param parent the parent of the node from which to search
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if the target element is not found
     */
    private T removeElement(T targetElement, BinaryTreeNode<T> node, BinaryTreeNode<T> parent)
    throws ElementNotFoundException 
    {
        T result = null;

        if (node == null)
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");
        else
        {
            if (((Comparable<T>)targetElement).equals(node.element)) 
            {
                result =  node.element;
                BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = replacement(node);
                if (parent.right == node)
                    parent.right = temp;
                else 
                    parent.left = temp;

                modCount--;
            }
            else 
            {                
                parent = node;
                if (((Comparable)targetElement).compareTo(node.element) < 0)
                    result = removeElement(targetElement, node.getLeft(), parent);
                else
                    result = removeElement(targetElement, node.getRight(), parent);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to a node that will replace the one
     * specified for removal.  In the case where the removed node has 
     * two children, the inorder successor is used as its replacement.
     *
     * @param node the node to be removed
     * @return a reference to the replacing node
     */
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> replacement(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> result = null;

        if ((node.left == null) && (node.right == null))
            result = null;

        else if ((node.left != null) && (node.right == null))
            result = node.left;

        else if ((node.left == null) && (node.right != null))
            result = node.right;

        else
        {
            BinaryTreeNode<T> current = node.right;
            BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = node;

            while (current.left != null)
            {
                parent = current;
                current = current.left;
            }

            current.left = node.left;
            if (node.right != current)
            {
                parent.left = current.right;
                current.right = node.right;
            }

            result = current;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Removes elements that match the specified target element from 
     * the binary search tree. Throws a ElementNotFoundException if 
     * the specified target element is not found in this tree.
     *
     * @param targetElement the element being sought in the binary search tree
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if the target element is not found
     */
    public void removeAllOccurrences(T targetElement)
                   throws ElementNotFoundException 
    {
        removeElement(targetElement);

        try
        {
            while (contains((T)targetElement))
                removeElement(targetElement);
        }

        catch (Exception ElementNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the node with the least value from the binary search
     * tree and returns a reference to its element.  Throws an
     * EmptyCollectionException if this tree is empty. 
     *
     * @return a reference to the node with the least value
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    public T removeMin() throws EmptyCollectionException 
    {
        T result = null;

        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");
        else 
        {
            if (root.left == null) 
            {
                result = root.element;
                root = root.right;
            }
            else 
            {
                BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = root;
                BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root.left;
                while (current.left != null) 
                {
                    parent = current;
                    current = current.left;
                }
                result =  current.element;
                parent.left = current.right;
            }

            modCount--;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the node with the highest value from the binary
     * search tree and returns a reference to its element.  Throws an
     * EmptyCollectionException if this tree is empty. 
     *
     * @return a reference to the node with the highest value
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    public T removeMax() throws EmptyCollectionException 
    {

         T result = null;

         if (isEmpty())
              throw new EmptyCollectionException ("binary tree");
         else 
         {
            if (root.right == null) 
            {
               result =  root.element;
               root = root.left;
            } //if
            else 
            {
                 BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = root;
                 BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root.right;

                 while (current.right != null) 
                 {
                    parent = current;
                    current = current.right;
                 } //while

                 result =  current.element;
                 parent.right = current.left;
              } //else

            modCount--;
         } //else

         return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element with the least value in the binary search
     * tree. It does not remove the node from the binary search tree. 
     * Throws an EmptyCollectionException if this tree is empty.
     *
     * @return the element with the least value
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    public T findMin() throws EmptyCollectionException 
    {

        T result = null;

        if (isEmpty())
             throw new EmptyCollectionException ("binary tree");
        else 
        {
           BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root;

           while (current.left != null)
              current = current.left;

           result = current.element;
        } //else

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element with the highest value in the binary
     * search tree.  It does not remove the node from the binary
     * search tree.  Throws an EmptyCollectionException if this 
     * tree is empty.
     *
     * @return the element with the highest value
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty
     */
    public T findMax() throws EmptyCollectionException 
    {
         T result = null;

         if (isEmpty())
              throw new EmptyCollectionException ("binary tree");
         else 
         {
            BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root;

            while (current.right != null)
               current = current.right;

           result = current.element;
         } //else

         return result;

    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the specified target element if it is
     * found in the binary tree.  Throws a NoSuchElementException if
     * the specified target element is not found in this tree.
     *
     * @param targetElement the element being sought in the binary tree
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if the target element is not found
     */
    public T find(T targetElement) throws ElementNotFoundException 
    {

        BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root; 
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = current;


         if (!(current.element.equals(targetElement)) && (current.left !=null)&&(((Comparable)current.element).compareTo(targetElement) > 0))
        current = findNode( targetElement, current.left);

         else if (!(current.element.equals(targetElement)) && (current.right != null)) 
        current = findNode( targetElement, current.right); 

         if (!(current.element.equals(targetElement)))
            throw new ElementNotFoundException ("binarytree");

         return current.element;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the left subtree of the root of this tree.
     *
     * @return a link to the left subtree of the tree
     */
    public LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> getLeft()
    {
        if (root == null) 
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("getLeft failed - the tree is empty");
        LinkedBinarySearchTree <T> result = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> ();
        result.root = root.getLeft();
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the right subtree of the root of this tree.
     *
     * @return a link to the right subtree of the tree
     */
    public LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> getRight()
    {

        if (root == null) 
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("getLeft failed - the tree is empty");
        LinkedBinarySearchTree <T> result = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> ();
        result.root = root.getRight();
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the specified target element if it is
     * found in this tree.  
     *
     * @param targetElement the element being sought in the tree
     * @param next the tree node to begin searching on
     */
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> findNode(T targetElement, BinaryTreeNode<T> next) 
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> current = next;
        if (!(next.element.equals(targetElement)) && (next.left !=null) &&(((Comparable)next.element).compareTo(targetElement) > 0))
        next = findNode( targetElement, next.left); 
        else if (!(next.element.equals(targetElement)) && (next.right != null))
        next = findNode( targetElement, next.right);                     

     return next;
    }

    /*balances the binary search tree so that it maintains
     * the maximum difference of the path lengths of the 
     * left and right children as not more than one*/
    public void balance() {
        //verify if balance factor of the root of the tree is -2
        if(getBalanceFactor(root) == -2) {
            //verify if balance factor of left child of tree root is 1
            if(getBalanceFactor(root.left) == 1)
                root = leftRightRotation(root);
            else 
                root = rightRotation(root);

        }
        //verify if balance factor of tree root is 2
        else if(getBalanceFactor(root) == 2) {
            //verify if balance factor of right child of tree root is -1
            if(getBalanceFactor(root.right) == -1) {
                root = rightLeftRotation(root);
            }
            else 
                root = leftRotation(root);
        }
    }

    /*performs right rotation and left rotation, then returns new root*/
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> rightLeftRotation(BinaryTreeNode<T> current) {
        current.right  = rightRotation(current.right);

        current = leftRotation(current);

        return current;
    }

    /*performs left rotation then right rotation then returns new root*/
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> leftRightRotation(BinaryTreeNode<T> current) {
        current.left = leftRotation(current.left);

        current = rightRotation(current);

        return current;
    }

    /*returns new root after performing right rotation of specified node*/
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> rightRotation(BinaryTreeNode<T> current) {

        BinaryTreeNode<T> newRoot = current.left;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = newRoot.right;

        newRoot.right = current;

        current.left = temp;

        return newRoot;
    }

    //returns new root after performing left rotation of specified node
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> leftRotation(BinaryTreeNode<T> current) {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> newRoot = current.right;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = newRoot.left;

        newRoot.left = current;

        current.right = temp;

        return newRoot;
    }

    //returns difference between path lengths of heights of left and right sides of root
    private int getBalanceFactor(BinaryTreeNode<T> current) {
        int leftHeight = getHeight(current.left);

        int rightHeight = getHeight(current.right);

        return(rightHeight - leftHeight);
    }

    //returns the height of the specified node
    private int getHeight(BinaryTreeNode<T> newRoot) {
        if(newRoot == null)
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(newRoot.left), getHeight(newRoot.right));

    }

}
```

Here's my driver program where my utlimate goal is to create the binary search tree from the image above, balance it, and test if it is balanced:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class IsHeightBalanced {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedBinarySearchTree<int> tree = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<int>;

        tree.addElement(13);
        tree.addElement(7);
        tree.addElement(15);
        tree.addElement(5);
        tree.addElement(10);
        tree.addElement(3);


    }

}
```

Right now I'm just trying to construct that binary search tree from the picture here and the line

```
LinkedBinarySearchTree<int> tree = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<int>();
```

is giving me errors like "insert dimensions to complete reference type"

Why is this giving such an error? Am I on the right track to creating the binary search tree seen in the picture above? Thanks.

Comment: There's _too much_ detail in this question, and it's not helping at all. Try to reduce the example to the smallest thing which highlights your issues. Here's [the guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to asking a question.

Comment: You can't use primitive types (like int) as generic type. use Integer.

Comment: Try `LinkedBinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>();`

You can't use _int_ as a generic type.

Comment: @JulienRousé what could i do to print the root value of the tree?

Comment: @JohnnySack `tree.getRootNode().getElement()` as the code you posted suggest.

Comment: @JulienRousé Thanks! Could I also get the balance factor of the tree in the same way if I make that method public instead of private?

Comment: @JohnnySack I don't understand what you mean by "that method"? Edit: ok i think you mean the `private int getBalanceFactor(BinaryTreeNode<T> current)`. I guess yes you could di it that way or writing a public method calling it.

Comment: @JulienRousé I did that but it needs BinaryTreeNode<T> current parameter. how would i call this in the driver class?

Comment: @JohnnySack you pass it the root node to get the balance factor of your whole tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types.
for an example

Consider the following parameterized type:

```
class Pair<K, V> {

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

When creating a Pair object, you cannot substitute a primitive type for the type parameter K or V:

```
Pair<int, char> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');  // compile-time error
```

You can substitute only non-primitive types for the type parameters K and V:

```
Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');
```

Note that the Java compiler autoboxes 8 to Integer.valueOf(8) and 'a' to Character('a'):

```
Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(8), new Character('a'));
```

Comment: what could i do to return the root value of the tree?

Comment: If you want return value then  create a method v getValue() and when you will assign to a primitive type it will Autoboxing happen.